# Do fish increase or decrease pH of aquarium water?

Tags: ichthyology

If I understand it correctly, aquarium fish produce NH<sub>3</sub> as their waste product and CO<sub>2</sub> due to respiration. Producing NH<sub>3</sub> increases water pH due to its equilibrium with NH<sub>4</sub><sup>+</sup>. Producing CO<sub>2</sub> decreases pH due to its equilibrium with H<sub>2</sub>CO<sub>3</sub> and its equilibrium with HCO<sub>3</sub><sup>-</sup>. My question is: Which of these effects is more important in most common aquarium fish? Do fish increase or decrease water pH?

Answer (score 5):

Like a glass of beer going flat, any excess CO<sub>2</sub> that your fish produce will quickly and irreversibly escape into the atmosphere. Thus, at least in terms of the pH battle between NH<sub>3</sub> and CO<sub>2</sub> that you describe, NH<sub>3</sub> would win.

#### boilerplate "science is complicated" disclaimer

That said, it's likely that the total environmental effect that fish have on a tiny non-circulating volume of water will be much more complicated than the interaction between two basic chemicals. For example, say one of your fish sheds some scales and they start to rot. All sorts of things would be happening at that point which could affect the pH.